# Google script не находит таблицу по имени

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть некий скрипт, который должен получить из запроса `POST` параметры и записать их в таблицу Google Sheet. Вот код скрипта:

```
function doGet(e){
   handle(e);
}

function doPost(e){
   handle(e);
}

function handle(request){
  var productName = request.parameter.name;
  var quantity = request.parameter.quantity;
  var amount = request.parameter.amount;
  var id = request.parameter.id;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var rowContent = sheet.appendRow([productName, quantity, amount]);
}
```

Проект развернут как веб приложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот таблица. Доступ открыт, глобально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда выполняю запрос из Postman

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понимаю, что не может найти таблицу с таким именем, поэтому ругается. Но почему?

Comment: Попробуйте получить доступ так: SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1')

Comment: получилось найти с getActiveSheet(), но не знаю в каких случаях это работает. Когда она активна и когда нет?

Comment: Вот тут я уже не подскажу. Не большой специалист в гугл-скриптах. Просто знаю что у нас это работает ;)